# How to send array from servlet and receive in HTML jquery?

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets, jquery

I am parsing an uploaded XML file using dom, generating the string where hostname and osname is made into a string separated with a `,` delimiter. `s` is the variable with this string and I am sending it back to HTML using `response.getWriter` object `obj`. But instead of printing it e.g.: `Windows,Abhishek` I'd like to split it with the delimiter `,`. Can someone show me example code of how I can receive this string in jQuery or JS and then split it into two strings?

```
try {
    out.println("Using Commons File Upload");
    List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator itr = items.iterator();
    String str=null;
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();

        if(item.isFormField()) {

            /*out.println("Form Input Name = "+item.getFieldName()+", Form Input Value = "+item.getString());*/
        } else {
            /*out.println("Field Name = "+item.getFieldName()+
                ", File Name = "+item.getName()+
                ", Content type = "+item.getContentType()+
                ", File Size = "+item.getSize());   */              
            File file = new File(destinationDir,item.getName());

            item.write(file);

            str=item.getName();

            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                File xmlFile = new File(destinationDir,str);

                if (file.exists()) {
                    Document doc = db.parse(xmlFile);
                    Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();

                    NodeList csmList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("system");

                    if (csmList != null && csmList.getLength() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < csmList.getLength(); i++) {

                            Node node = csmList.item(i);

                            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                                Element e = (Element) node;
                                NodeList nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("hostname");
                                s=nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                                //System.out.println("HOSTNAME: "+ nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());

                                nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("osname");
                                s+=","+nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                                //System.out.println("OSNAME: " + nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0) .getNodeValue());
                            }
                        }
                        out.println(s);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("File Not Found");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }

    }
    out.close();
    System.out.println(str);


}catch(FileUploadException ex) {
    log("Error encountered while parsing the request",ex);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    log("Error encountered while uploading file",ex);
}
```

Javascript part:

```
function postData() {
    $.post("/com/FileUploadServlet", { "file": "/com/FileUploadServlet" }, function(data) {
        alert(data); 
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    postData();
});
```

The `alert(data);` prints `"Using Commons File Upload"` but in the servlet `out.println(s);` does not give me my data in the alert, instead it comes blank.

Comment: Debug the code. What code in servlet get executed and what not? The symptoms indicate that the `s` is simply never populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that you're sending a comma-delimited string to the browser, and you want to split it by comma in Javascript/JQuery. Is that a reasonable summary of your question? I found it quite hard to read, but I think that's what you're asking, so that's what I'll answer. :)

Javascript has a `.split()` method, which you can use on any string variable.

So where you receive the string in your Javascript code, you can simply do something like this:

```
var splitstring = inputstring.split(',');
```

Hope that helps. (though I do get the feeling there's more to the question than my interpretation)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sorry for such big question, in short I'd like to know, w.r.t my code how will I receive the comma-delimited string in the same HTML page from where I submitted the upload file.

Comment: I managed to work it out, not by sending array but a string of text separated by `,` delimiter. Here is the link if some1 wants to have a look. http://elmicoxcodes.blogspot.com/2007/03/asynchronous-upload-like-ajax-1.html

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can convert an array in java as JSON string, and then on the javascript side make an object from it like this:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I used JSON, but now from inside DefaultHandler how do i pass the JSON Object? `JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
                    obj.put("host",summ[0]);
                    obj.put("name",summ[1]);`

Comment: Can you show me an example that will help me to pass this JSON Object from inside of DefaultHandler block and use it in jquery?

Comment: Hey, I edited my code. Now it seem much easier to pass data, as its only array of strings, so I can pass with some delimiter. I'd like to know how would I receive the strings from my servlet to the same html page from where I uploaded file, to show the string (servlet returned string).